# Laravel JWT-auth get custom claim before looking up user information

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have a custom claim 'company' set in a json web token. I need to evaluate the token to pull out the 'company' to set up a database connection before looking up the user.

In other words I need to execute this code before checking the database for user login/password.

```
    $payload = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload();
    $system = System::where('company', '=', $payload['company'])->first();
    if(!$system)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }
    $system->createTenantConnection();
```

Before using JWT I had some middleware to do this.

## UPDATE

I copied `\Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken` and modified it to fit my needs.... it is probably the wrong way to go about it but it worked....

1st changed app/Http/Kernal.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // 'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    // 'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    //'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\customGetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
];
```

Then copied and pasted Tymon's code to a new file and added in my code.

I'll think it over instead of sleeping...looks like I should just make my own middleware first to check the custom claims

Update

I modified the route.php to add in a middleware before jwt auth:

```
$api->group( [ 'middleware' => ['company','jwt.auth'] ], function ($api) {....}
```

then added company to kernal.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // 'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        // 'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'company' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckCompany::class,
        'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
//        'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\customGetUserFromToken::class,
        'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
    ];
```

then created `CheckCompany.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: embrasse-moi
 * Date: 11/25/16
 * Time: 9:44 PM
 */

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


//use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
//use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use App\Models\Craiglorious\System;

class CheckCompany extends BaseMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if ( ! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken())
        {
            return $this->respond('tymon.jwt.absent', 'token_not_provided', 400);
        }
        $payload = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload();
        $system = System::where('company', '=', $payload['company'])->first();
        if ( ! $system)
        {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
        $system->createTenantConnection();
        //dd($system->company);
        //dd($token);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I think this looks good....

Comment: Wow this was an extremely timely answer. Thanks! Will post my own if I see I can improve on this method.

Comment: This work. But is it the right way.